# Condição IF com banco de dados

Tags: php, html, banco-de-dados

Pessoal eu estou fazendo um sistema de transferencia de dinheiro via php com banco de dados, tenho um option mostrando todos os usuarios do banco de dados e um campo de texto para inserir um valor, como eu faço para que o usuario nao consiga selecionar ele mesmo e aumentar o seu dinheiro

Codigo do campo:

```
$result_usuario = "SELECT usuario FROM `usuarios`";
$mostra_dados = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
while($rows_cursos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mostra_dados)){
<option name="id" value="<?php echo $rows_cursos['id'];?>"><?php echo $rows_cursos['usuario'];?></option>
```

Codigo para fazer o update e verificação:

```
if ($id['id'] == $rows1['id']){
    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
    echo "<br><div class='alert alert-success'>Impossivel enviar dinheiro para voce mesmo ESPERTALHÂO</div>";
} elseif ($dinheiro > $rows['dinheiro']){
    $_SESSION['dinheiro'] = $dinheiro;
    echo "<br><div class='alert alert-success'> Sem Dinheiro Suficiente seu saldo de dinheiro em carteira é de ". $rows2['dinheiro'] ." Reais </div>";
} else {
    $recebe_dados1 = "UPDATE usuarios SET dinheiro = dinheiro -'$dinheiro' WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['usuarioId'] ."'"; 
    $recebe_dados2 = "UPDATE usuarios SET dinheiro = dinheiro +'$dinheiro' WHERE id = '".$rows1['id'] ."'"; 
    $recebe_dados4 = "UPDATE usuarios SET total = dinheiro + depositado WHERE id = '". $_SESSION['usuarioId'] ."'";
    echo "<script>window.location='?pagina=logado';alert('Você fez uma transferencia de $dinheiro Reais.');</script>";
```

Comment: Tem login? Vc armazena algum identificador do usuário?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu código tem uma inconsistência. Talvez mais... Mas vou citar uma que está bem clara pra mim.

Neste select você seleciona apenas o campo usuario e depois quer tentar utilizar o id. Logo, isso não irá funcionar. O certo seria assim:

```
"SELECT id,usuario FROM `usuarios`"
```

Para você selecionar todos os usuários menos o que está logado, você pode fazer isso direto no banco:

```
$result_usuario = "SELECT id,usuario FROM `usuarios` WHERE NOT id = ".$_SESSION['id'];
```

Desta forma o espertalhão não irá conseguir selecionar ele mesmo.

Lógico que no momento que for fazer a transferência é bom ver se ele não deu um jeito de lançar o próprio id. Esse `if` eu faria algo assim:

```
if ($_SESSION['id'] != $_POST['id'] && $dinheiro >= $_POST['dinheiro']){
    // transferindo...
    // update...
}
```

Comment: Obrigado eu consegui fazer so com isso mesmo $result_usuario = "SELECT id,usuario FROM `usuarios` WHERE NOT id = ".$_SESSION['id'];

Comment: @mateussilva legal! Mas cuidado...  O homem prevenido morreu de velho.

Comment: kkkkk, gostei do `espertalhão`, termo bem aplicado, mais ainda do `WHERE NOT` vai meu +1

Comment: kkk valeu @LeoCaracciolo